# Vectorizing the concatenation of binary operations

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, logical-operators

Say I have a cell array, that holds a stack of logical matrices, e.g.

```
matrices = 
    [225x400 logical]
    [225x400 logical]
    ....
    [225x400 logical]
```

The cell array can potentially hold hundreds of matrices.

I would like to compute a single matrix that is the result of the concatenation of binary operations on this matrices.

i.e.

```
result = matrices{1} & matrices{2} & matrices{3} & ..., etc.
```

**My question:** Is it possible to do this without looping? And if so, is there any benefit in vectorizing this computation MATLAB?

What if the stack of matrices is represented as a 3D array (instead of a cell array?), e.g.:

```
  Name                        Size                  

  matrices                  225x400x100
```

Is there any benefit in holding these types of stacks as cell arrays vs 3D matrices? (to clarify, in this last example, we would compute the `AND` of `100` matrices, each of them of size `225x400`).

**PS:** I'm interested in solutions to `AND`, `XOR` and `OR`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do vectorized computations on cell arrays. You have to convert it to a 3D array (using `cell2mat`), or even better: pre-allocate a 3D array.

Then, with dimensions 225x400x100 you can do:

or:

```
any(matrices,3)
```

and:

```
all(matrices,3)
```

xor:

```
mod( sum(matrices, 3), 2)
```

The benefit of cell arrays is memory preservation (e.g., once you delete a cell). Once your cell array is stable you should turn it into a matrix for vectorized computations, which is much faster than Matlab loops.

Comment: to convert from cellarray to 3D matrix, use the following: `cat(3,matrices{:})`